# Rotational energy with moment of inertia tensor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-kinematics, moment-of-inertia

Some objects have a single moment of inertia value while others like ellipsoids have a tensor, if I wanted to work out the rotational energy of an oblate spheroid rotating around its z axis could I just use $I_{zz}$ for an ellipsoid in $E=\frac{1}{2}I\omega^2$ or do they combine somehow?

[image]

Comment: write the vector $\{\omega _x, \omega _y,\omega _z\}$, then calculate the product of the matrix $I$ with that vector. You get a vector, $\vec {(I\omega)}$. Also, pay attention that $\frac {I\omega^2}{2} = \vec {(I\omega)} \cdot \vec {\omega}$.